# How do you make this complex HTML table without CSS?

Tags: html, user-interface

I need the table with 2 columns, column 1 has 3 cells and column 2 has only 2 cells.

[image]

so far I came to know that I cannot do it without CSS (height attribute on cell 4 and 5), is there any way to do it with pure HTML ? No CSS ?

```html
        <table border="1px" cellpadding="50px">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="1">1</td>
                <td rowspan="2">4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="1">3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: How it will render without set heights is based on the contents.

Comment: I also need answer for this, I actually saw a quite similar table when I was searching for some difficult exercises on HTML tables.

Comment: Tables really are not meant for layout. They will collapse to the best fit when rendered unless you tell it how it should render.

Comment: this is not for layout purpose anyway, just an exercise of complex html tables. I am wondering if it can be done without CSS, only with pure HTML.

Comment: It is done, problem is the layout just flattens out without content in it.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is used for telling the software how to render HTML. I am quite sure (although I may be wrong) that there is no way to do this without CSS.